# Java Random - How can one of two equal values be different than the other?

Tags: java, swing, random, int

Take a look at this code:

```
        while(oneRay[pick][0] == "" || oneRay[pick][0] == null)
        hold = oneRay.length;
        random = new Random(); 
        System.out.println(oneRay.length + "\n" + hold);
        pick = random.nextInt(hold);
        System.exit(0);
    }
```

In the console output, I see 33 and then 0. How does that make any sense? First, I set hold equal to the length of oneRay, then I print the length of oneRay followed by hold, should I not see 33 and 33 or at worst 0 and 0?
I know some of you have seen my many questions tonight but I cannot get past this loop, there is always some error or another, and in this case the Random wont proceed as the value of hold is 0...
Please help me!

Comment: use `equals` to compare observational equality of objects. `==` is for references

Comment: Yep. When you use `==` with objects, you're comparing memory addresses, not the values. Probably not what you want to be doing.

Answer (score 5):

You used

```
while(oneRay[pick][0] == "" || oneRay[pick][0] == null)
```

and then you didn't use brackets, which means that your code actually works like

```
while(oneRay[pick][0] == "" || oneRay[pick][0] == null) {
    hold = oneRay.length;
}
random = new Random(); 
System.out.println(oneRay.length + "\n" + hold);
```

In particular, if the `while` condition doesn't hold, then `hold = oneRay.length` won't even be executed.

(You should also be using `.equals("")` or `.isEmpty` rather than `== ""`, and you should be doing the null check first instead of second.)